# "used struct type value where scalar is required" at .layer.position

Tags: objective-c

I want to make a selection before apply one of two animations, 
what I thought is: make a Point `one`, if my `myImageView` is at the Point `one`, then apply `animationNo1`, else apply `animationNo2`, but I got this:"used struct type value where scalar is required", at line `if (myImageView.layer.position = one)`

What I do? how can I fix this?
Does anyone know exactly what makes the problem happen?

```
 CGPoint one = CGPointMake(myImageView.layer.position.x, 100);

 if (myImageView.layer.position = one) 
 {
       animationNo1
 }

 else 
 {
       animationNo2
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your if-statement will not do what you think. If you want to compare something you have to use == (ie 2 =)

and you can't compare CGPoints like this.

use

```
 if (CGPointEqualToPoint(one, self.view.layer.position))
```

Comment: I tried CGPointEqualToPoint to compare, it works fine, Thank you :)

Comment: @flutewang: You should accept his answer out to thank him for his help.

Answer (score 2):

`if (myImageView.layer.position = one) { animationNo1 }`

should be

`if (CGPointIsEqualToPoint(myImageView.layer.position, one)) { animationNo1 }`

You used a single = meaning assignment, rather than a == for comparison. But the == wouldn't do what you wanted here anyway.

Comment: thank you for remind me to use == to compare, CGPointEqualToPoint works great! it should be CGPointEqualToPoint, without "Is" in the middle

Comment: Thats what I get for typing in functions without checking the docs :)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a struct (int this case position) instead of a scalar. To do what you want you need to use CGPointIsEqualToPoint:

```
if (CGPointEqualToPoint(one, self.view.layer.position))
```

Full code with corrections:

```
CGPoint one = CGPointMake(myImageView.layer.position.x, 100);

if (CGPointEqualToPoint(one, self.view.layer.position))
{
      animationNo1
}

else 
{
      animationNo2
}
```

Also, as others have pointed out: Be careful about = vs ==. They are different. In this case you don't use == for comparison fortunately, but if you use = for other stuff it will make it true instead of checking to see if it is true.

Comment: thanks, thyrgle, i carry lots of ideas to start programming, it's tough to achieve what I'm thinking, seems i need to browse more dictionaries from apple and the language itself, thank you guys! you are all very kind! :)