# i want to make an if statement, so if some images are on a specific coordinate, there will be a sound

Tags: ios, if-statement, ios6, xcode4.5, cgpoint

i know how to make playin a sound but i don't know how to use the 'CGPointisEqualtoPoint' method. How do i use that or are there other ways?

```
-(void)beloning {
if (//CGPointisEqualtoPoint?!
    )  {
    //play sound
}
```

Comment: A `UIButton` would not do?

Comment: You should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897330/used-struct-type-value-where-scalar-is-required-at-layer-position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the docs:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html)

> Returns whether two points are equal.

```
bool CGPointEqualToPoint (
     CGPoint point1,
    CGPoint point2
);
```

But you may be better off with this one:

> CGRectContainsPoint
>   Returns whether a rectangle contains a specified point.

```
bool CGRectContainsPoint (
     CGRect rect,
     CGPoint point
);
```

So now you can check if the rect of your image contains the coordinate point you care about